# iOS app crashes when the simulator window is moved

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I’m working on a universal iOS application that runs fine on both the iPad Air and iPhone 5. Sometimes (1 out of ~5 times), when I move the simulator window, it crashes. I don’t get a usable error log nor a stack trace. It just seems the app get’s terminated and I do get a beach ball. I did add an "Exception Breakpoint” but it does not fire. The simulator itself does *not* crash. I can still use the shortcut for the home button and restart my application.

I do have 16GB of Ram. I don’t think it’s a memory problem.

Do I invoke something on my app when I move the simulator window? I can’t reproduce this behaviour, but it happened to me multiple times a day since I updated Xcode. Does anybody else have this problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Moving the simulator window shouldn't affect the running app. I would log a bug with Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Moving the simulator window doesn't affect the running app at all.  That is likely coincidental.  Any crashes will be logged to ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

Comment: I thought so too Jeremy, but even 1 month later I didn’t have a single crash on my device and the app regulary crashes when moving the simulator window. I can’t explain it. It does not get terminated, it just crashes.